# Restrict access to values based on profile

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have a field which is a picklist. I want to restrict access to the values in this field based on profile so that certain profiles can only see eg. only 3 values out of 10. others could see 5.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict picklist values, you would need to create separate record types for the object and assign them to your different profiles. You can then edit the available values within the record types on the object.